# JSON structure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript structure that looks like that:

```
[{'red': {color:'red},...}]
```

starting with an array of colors:

```
const COLORS = ['red','yellow']
```

This is what I have tried:

const finalArray = COLORS.map(color => ({ [color]: { color } }))

However this produces an array that looks like that:

```
[{red: {color:'red'}}]
```

instead of [{'red': {color:'red'}}]

Which is not the same and will prevent the library I am using from understanding the array.

Any idea is welcome.

I edited the question since there where some typos. Hope it’s clearer now.

Thanks

Comment: `However this produces an array that looks like that: [...] instead of` They are the same?!

Comment: Whether the property name is quoted or not, they are the same

Comment: They are the same thing. The object property names can be wrapped in single or double quotes but the quoting is not required if the name is a valid variable name.

Comment: In javascript, an object noted by `{ 'red': 'something' }`  and `{ red: 'something' }` are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just two ways of *representing* the same array/object. If you need a *string* containing the *canonical representation* of the array/object (with double quotes around the names of the properties), you can use JSON.stringify(finalArray).

Please note this will quote ALL your property names, like in:

```
[{"red":{"color":"red"}}]
```

And please note the above is a string, as if you did:

```
finalString = '[{"red":{"color":"red"}}]'
```

(Note: this question has been closed, and I agree it's not clear enough. But it's quite evident that the user is confusing the *internal structure* of an array/object with its *external representation*, and with the way the array/object is shown by a development environment, browser, etc. As this is a very common problem, mostly in new programmers or newcomers to a tool, the question and the answers may still be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

What are the differences between:

```
[{red: {color:'red'}}]
// and
[{'red': {color:'red'}}]
```

If it's only a quote related matters, you can do like:

```
COLORS.map(color => ({ [`'${color}'`]: { color } }));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. As for all the other answers quoting that I am obviously mixing object definition with arrays, let’s say I typed the question from my phone and forgot the opening and closing ‘}’ but I see with pleasure that you and some others have automatically corrected the typo. Nice to see that there are still people on stack overflow that read a question with the premise that the author is not atupid. Thanks bud, simple solution I didn’t think about that. Appreciated.

Comment: @user2097439 it might be quite rude, but don't forget to mark this on "solved" to help other people with same issue to be redirected to the appropried answer

Comment: Sorry, thanks for reminding me, done!

Comment: I have to say this answer may be misleading, because it adds the (single) quotes to the property name, and you end up with something like: `[{"'red'":{"color":"red"}}`. You can check it at [https://playcode.io/1189383](https://playcode.io/1189383).

Comment: @user2097439 Nobody wanted to be harsh on you. And it's not a matter of arrays vs. objects (nobody said that). It's about internal vs. external representation. Is your library written in JavaScript and does it expect an object? Then forget about quotes (except when these quotes are part of a property name). Or does it expect a string (ie. an external representation of the object)?